# “to render a template” in German

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german, word-choice

I am from Germany and have to write a code documentation. Since I try to use as many German words as possible, it is sometimes difficult to do so. I want to say

> This View renders a given template

which I currently would translate into

> Dieser View rendert ein gegebenes Template

An explanation what *render* actually means:

> Rendering a view means showing up a View eg html part to user or
>   browser. Let's say you have a controller for About page of your site,
>   now from your controller you would render the About view which means
>   show the that page in browser for users to see otherwise if you don't
>   users will see just blank page :)

[Reference to the quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233442/what-does-it-mean-to-render-a-view-what-the-procedure-is-this)

Since this is not fully German, I try to find another good expression for this. What bothers me the most is the word *rendern.* Do you guys have a good solution for this?

Comment: Wenn Du schon View und Template stehen lässt, würde ich mir um rendern nicht mehr den Kopf zerbrechen...

Comment: @Robert Hm auch ein gutes Argument

Comment: Für die Zukunft: Du weißt, dass du hier auch auf Deutsch fragen kannst? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rendern](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/rendern) ist ein deutsches Wort und sollte von jedem verstanden werden, der mit Views und Templates hantiert.
Je nach (Arbeits?)Umfeld können diese englischen Begriffe im Einzelfall auch übersetzt werden, das ändert jedoch nichts an der "fachlichen Korrektheit" oder Verständlichkeit.

Falls eine Übersetzung zwingend erforderlich ist, schlage ich "darstellen" oder "umsetzen" vor, meinetwegen auch aus der Welt der Formulare gemopst "ausfüllen". Rendern trifft allerdings genauer.

Answer (score 7):

[*Rendern*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/rendern) ist, wie in der [anderen Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/27326/5999) beschrieben, ein deutsches Wort. Meiner Erfahrung nach ist die Bedeutung von *rendern* aber deutlich enger als die von *to render* im Englischen, sodass der Ausdruck *rendern* **an dieser Stelle möglicherweise falsch** ist:

Im Englischen bezeichnet *to render* so ungefähr jede Darstellung, die in irgendeiner Form berechnet wird. Dies schließt reine Textdokumente und Webseiten ein, die formatiert auf dem Bildschirm ausgegeben werden.

Im Deutschen scheint *rendern* eher gezielt auf 3D-Grafiken oder 3D-ähnliche Grafiken abzuzielen, und zudem noch auf die Erstellung fertiger Videodateien aus Rohdaten. Ein Dokument wird im Deutschen im Allgemeinen nicht von einem Browser oder einem anderen Betrachtungsprogramm "gerendert", ein Szenenmodell wird jedoch von einem Raytracer "gerendert".

- Diese speziellere Bedeutung wird beispielsweise im [Wikipedia-Artikel zu *rendern*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendern_%28Design%29) angedeutet, in dem das Wort *rendern* mit den 3D-Programmen [POV-Ray](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/POV-Ray) und [Cinema 4D](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinema_4D) sowie mit Videobearbeitung in Zusammenhang gebracht wird.
- Ebenso ist auffallend, dass Anfragen an [Google Images](https://images.google.com/) sowohl nach *rendered image* als auch nach *gerendertes bild* Unmengen an (fast ausschließlich) 3D-Grafiken zum Vorschein bringen. *rendered document* fördert eine ähnlich große Ergebnisliste mit auf Bildschirmen und in Benutzeroberflächen dargestellten Textdokumenten zu Tage, während *gerendertes Dokument* momentan gerade mal 26 Ergebnisse liefert.

Im gegebenen Fall würde ich einfach ein anderes Verb wählen, da *darstellen* oder *anzeigen* genauso gut zu passen scheinen:

> Dieser View stellt ein gegebenes Template dar
>
> Dieser View zeigt ein gegebenes Template an

Zudem scheint *View* öfters als Femininum behandelt zu werden (wohl in Analogie zur ebenfalls femininen *Ansicht*), sodass auch *Diese View ...* denkbar wäre.

Answer (score 1):

Diese Ansicht stellt eine gegebene Schablone dar.

Comment: *Schablone* könnte richtig sein, in den meisten Software-bezogenen Kontexten wäre das aber unpassend und *Vorlage* wäre die richtige Übersetzung (und in bestimmten Situationen ist auch tatsächlich *Template* das einzige gebräuchliche Wort).